# What's a word for when you try to be something?

Tags: adverbs

I don't mean it in a way where you're trying to be something that you're not, rather, where you're trying to be more of something that you already are (maybe not 100% of the time but you still have been it before)
If that even makes sense?

P.s. It doesn't have to be an adverb, I'm just not good with choosing tags...

Answer (score 2):

Someday, being a firefighter is my

> aspiration
>
> as·pi·ra·tion
>
> ˌaspəˈrāSH(ə)n/
>
> noun
>
> 1. a hope or ambition of achieving something.
>
> "he had nothing tangible to back up his literary aspirations"
>
> synonyms:  desire, hope, dream, wish, longing, yearning; aim, ambition, expectation, goal, target
>
> "his greatest aspiration is to win an Olympic gold medal"
>
> 2. MEDICINE
>
> the action or process of drawing breath.
>
> [google: aspiration](https://www.google.com/search?q=Asperation&oq=Asperation&aqs=chrome..69i57&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#q=Aspiration)